# Speeding "SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS" SQL queries for a large database

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, plugins, web-crawler

I am using a WordPress plugin called [feedwordpress](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/feedwordpress/) in order to run a planet like website on wordpress (See it [here](http://www.r-bloggers.com/)).

The plugin is great except for one thing - it hogs down my (VPS) server into submission once every week or so.

In a recent e-mail exchange with the webadmin he wrote the following:

> It does look like the increased mysql
>   resource usage is being caused by slow
>   queries being run by r-bloggers.com.
>   Here is a copy of some of the logs
>   that are being produced. You would
>   need to optimize this site and
>   database further to have it running as
>   efficiently as possible. If these
>   changes have already been made, your
>   best option would be to look into a
>   large upgrade for your VPS due to the
>   high level or resources and traffic
>   that your site needs and sees.

Here are the logs:

```
# Time: 110614 16:11:35
# User@Host: rblogger_rblogr[rblogger_rblogr] @ localhost []
# Query_time: 104 Lock_time: 0 Rows_sent: 0 Rows_examined: 54616
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_rb_posts.* FROM wp_rb_posts WHERE 1=1 AND ((guid = '235cbefa4424d0cdb7b6213f15a95ded') OR (guid = 'http://www.r-bloggers.com/?guid=235cbefa4424d0cdb7b6213f15a95ded') OR (guid = 'http://www.r-bloggers.com/?guid=235cbefa4424d0cdb7b6213f15a95ded') OR (MD5(guid) = '235cbefa4424d0cdb7b6213f15a95ded')) AND wp_rb_posts.post_type IN ('post', 'page', 'attachment', 'revision', 'nav_menu_item') AND (wp_rb_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_rb_posts.post_status = 'future' OR wp_rb_posts.post_status = 'draft' OR wp_rb_posts.post_status = 'pending' OR wp_rb_posts.post_status = 'trash' OR wp_rb_posts.post_status = 'auto-draft' OR wp_rb_posts.post_status = 'inherit' OR wp_rb_posts.post_status = 'private') ORDER BY wp_rb_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 1570, 10;
# User@Host: rblogger_rblogr[rblogger_rblogr] @ localhost []
# Query_time: 237 Lock_time: 0 Rows_sent: 0 Rows_examined: 54616
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_rb_posts.* FROM wp_rb_posts WHERE 1=1 AND ((guid = '235cbefa4424d0cdb7b6213f15a95ded') OR (guid = 'http://www.r-bloggers.com/?guid=235cbefa4424d0cdb7b6213f15a95ded') OR (guid = 'http://www.r-bloggers.com/?guid=235cbefa4424d0cdb7b6213f15a95ded') OR (MD5(guid) = '235cbefa4424d0cdb7b6213f15a95ded')) AND wp_rb_posts.post_type IN ('post', 'page', 'attachment', 'revision', 'nav_menu_item') AND (wp_rb_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_rb_posts.post_status = 'future' OR wp_rb_posts.post_status = 'draft' OR wp_rb_posts.post_status = 'pending' OR wp_rb_posts.post_status = 'trash' OR wp_rb_posts.post_status = 'auto-draft' OR wp_rb_posts.post_status = 'inherit' OR wp_rb_posts.post_status = 'private') ORDER BY wp_rb_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 570, 10;
# Time: 110614 16:18:13
# User@Host: rblogger_rblogr[rblogger_rblogr] @ localhost []
# Query_time: 257 Lock_time: 0 Rows_sent: 0 Rows_examined: 54616
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_rb_posts.* FROM wp_rb_posts WHERE 1=1 AND ((guid = '956e208f101562f6654e88e9711276e4') OR (guid = 'http://www.r-bloggers.com/?guid=956e208f101562f6654e88e9711276e4') OR (guid = 'http://www.r-bloggers.com/?guid=956e208f101562f6654e88e9711276e4') OR (MD5(guid) = '956e208f101562f6654e88e9711276e4')) AND wp_rb_posts.post_type IN ('post', 'page', 'attachment', 'revision', 'nav_menu_item') AND (wp_rb_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_rb_posts.post_status = 'future' OR wp_rb_posts.post_status = 'draft' OR wp_rb_posts.post_status = 'pending' OR wp_rb_posts.post_status = 'trash' OR wp_rb_posts.post_status = 'auto-draft' OR wp_rb_posts.post_status = 'inherit' OR wp_rb_posts.post_status = 'private') ORDER BY wp_rb_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 570, 10;
# Time: 110614 16:19:02
# User@Host: rblogger_rblogr[rblogger_rblogr] @ localhost []
# Query_time: 83 Lock_time: 0 Rows_sent: 0 Rows_examined: 54616
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_rb_posts.* FROM wp_rb_posts WHERE 1=1 AND ((guid = '6c589e661f03a67b0529fab2f080bfd3') OR (guid = 'http://www.r-bloggers.com/?guid=6c589e661f03a67b0529fab2f080bfd3') OR (guid = 'http://www.r-bloggers.com/?guid=6c589e661f03a67b0529fab2f080bfd3') OR (MD5(guid) = '6c589e661f03a67b0529fab2f080bfd3')) AND wp_rb_posts.post_type IN ('post', 'page', 'attachment', 'revision', 'nav_menu_item') AND (wp_rb_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_rb_posts.post_status = 'future' OR wp_rb_posts.post_status = 'draft' OR wp_rb_posts.post_status = 'pending' OR wp_rb_posts.post_status = 'trash' OR wp_rb_posts.post_status = 'auto-draft' OR wp_rb_posts.post_status = 'inherit' OR wp_rb_posts.post_status = 'private') ORDER BY wp_rb_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 1440, 10;
```

Which leads me to my question - what in this logs might indicate to me what is happening (why should such queries take so long?)? is it possible to optimize these?  If so, how?

Thanks,
Tal

Comment: I'm not very familiar with WordPress or MySQL in particular, but from looking at the query and the stats, the query is doing a table scan of all the posts. Assuming the `guid` column is supposed to be unique, adding an index on that column should do the trick.

Comment: @Jon: sadly, such an index already exists. And in this query, it's more than useless because of the inordinate amounts of ORs -- which MySQL will not handle from lack of being able to do an bitmap index scan.

Comment: @Denis: Looking closely at it again, probably the `MD5(guid)` would prevent the index from being used anyway. The query is pretty brutal-looking to start with. :(

Comment: @Jon: It's a rather hopeless situation insofar as I'm concerned, as I suggest in my answer. They won't want to even begin fixing it. And yes, the md5() call on the whole table certainly doesn't help either... :D

Comment: Hi Denis - thank you for shedding more light into this issue!  Since this query is used for a very specific purpose (this plugin), is there a way to limit it? (for example, by date of posts, or something like that?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being familiar with WordPress, I think you should append to one of the ongoing tickets on the topic, or create a new one.

http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/10469

http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/10964

http://core.trac.wordpress.org/search?q=SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS

Alternatively, give up and use more appropriate tools for the task.